# Trigonometric simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

How can I simplify `1/2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x])` in order to get `Cos[x + Pi/6]` on *Mathematica*? I saw that *Wolfram|Alpha* lists this simplification on the `AlternateForms`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `TrigFactor[]` function, as in

```
TrigFactor[1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x] - Sin[x])]
```

Output

```
Cos[Pi/6 + x].
```

Comment: That's great! But TrigFactor was not able to simplify the following expression:  1/2*((Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]-Sin[x])*m-n). I expect   m*Cos[x+Pi/6]-n/2  as the result.

Comment: Did you mean to have a parentheses around that $m-n$?

Comment: no. The expression is correct.

Comment: Well, that expression you have in comment is $\frac{1}{2} \left(m \left(\sqrt{3} \cos (x)-\sin (x)\right)-n\right)$. See that you can pull out the constant. $-\frac{n}{2}$. The remaining part will factor.

Comment: In other words, that's just $\frac{1}{2} m \left(\sqrt{3} \cos (x)-\sin (x)\right)-\frac{n}{2}$. The trig part will factor, the constant will not.

Comment: @Hermano Interestingly enough, in answering another question, I assembled a snippet which also appears to work efficiently on the expression in your comment: `Map[TrigFactor, HornerForm[1/2*((Sqrt[3]*Cos[x] - Sin[x])*m - n)]]` It breaks that constant off, and gives what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could call a function that fetches all WolframAlpha alternate expression forms:

```
AlternateExpressionForms[expression_]:=Module[{alternateFormData},
    alternateFormData={};
    alternateFormData=Quiet[Check[TimeConstrained[ReleaseHold[WolframAlpha[ToString[expression,InputForm],{"AlternateForm","Input"}]],60],{}]];
    Flatten[Table[alternateFormData[[i,2]],{i,Length[alternateFormData]}]]
]
SetAttributes[AlternateExpressionForms,Listable];
```

Example:

```
AlternateExpressionForms[1/2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x])]
(*==> {Cos[\[Pi]/6 + x], 1/2 Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x]/2, -(1/4) I E^(-I x) + 1/4 Sqrt[3] E^(-I x) + 1/4 I E^(I x) + 1/4 Sqrt[3] E^(I x)}*)
```